# Rabbitmq, ubuntu and auto-starting

Tags: ubuntu, rabbitmq, upstart

I want to auto start rabbitmq on ubuntu, with several vhosts and users existing.

How can I achieve this? I wrote a small upstart script as this:

```
description "Rabbit Application"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]
respawn
exec rabbitmq-server -detached
```

The problem is, when it starts, it doesn't have users or vhosts as I set up earlier (before the server reset), which I added via `sudo rabbitmqctl` commands.

Answer (score 0):

Which user context does RabbitMQ run under  when run through the script?

When running on Windows, if RabbitMQ start under my user account the queues/vhosts/users are different to when this is running as a Windows service.

The way that I got around this was by setting up some environment variables so that regardless of who is running RabbitMQ the same config is read and the same directory for queues etc are used. Take a look at http://www.rabbitmq.com/relocate.html for details.